# PhantomJS throws error on Angular 4 vendor.bundle when running ng test

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm having an issue after upgrading @angular/cli to version 1.7.4. I've already tried lower versions such as 1.6.x but this seems less related to the specific version and rather the way the bundles are built for testing. I also created a new Angular project to verify that the vendor/main bundles are pulled in the same way which they are.

When running `ng test` I get the following error in the console (debug level):

```
19 04 2018 10:14:11.861:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js /
19 04 2018 10:14:11.861:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js
19 04 2018 10:14:11.871:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js /
19 04 2018 10:14:11.871:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js
19 04 2018 10:14:13.500:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js /
19 04 2018 10:14:13.500:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js
19 04 2018 10:14:13.538:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js /
19 04 2018 10:14:13.538:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "SyntaxError: Parser error\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:264651:0",
    "str": "SyntaxError: Parser error\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:264651:0"
  }

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "SyntaxError: Parser error\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:264651:0",
    "str": "SyntaxError: Parser error\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:264651:0"
  }
```

The line number listed for the vendor file does not exist and actually isn't pointing to the real error. If launch a browser and point it at the Karma url it runs the tests fine. More infuriatingly it also restarts the tests in PhantomJS and they execute fine. Headless Chrome also works, but the build serve I'm sending this to is Jenkins and that team doesn't have support for anything besides PhantomJS.

If anyone has any thoughts I'd love some help. I've been banging my head against this for a whole day.

Relevant packages:

```
"@angular/animations": "4.3.6",
"@angular/common": "4.3.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.3.6",
"@angular/core": "4.3.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.3.6",
"@angular/http": "4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.6",
"@angular/platform-server": "4.3.6",
"@angular/router": "4.3.6",
 ...
"karma": "^2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
```